# Embed Group Photo from Microsoft Graph API into Web page

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a webpage written in AngularJS, and in it, I want to display the photo associated with a group.

I wrote code to do this, and I am able to get the base64 encoded data to display as a string, but not as an image. It always appears as a broken image.

Frontend:

```
<img ng-src="{{home.emails}}" />
```

Javascript:

```
$http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/0005cadf-00f7-4f16-8aef-527f576cdad9/photo/$value',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'image/jpg'
      }
    })
  .then(function(response) {

    var base64 = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + hexToBase64(response.data)
    vm.emails = base64;

    $log.debug(response.data);

  }, function(error) {
    $log.error('HTTP request to Mail API failed.');
  });
```

};

As a test, I took a code snippet from another stackoverflow post which provided a hex version of a jpg, and it displayed fine:

```
function getBinary() {
    return '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';
}

$http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/0005cadf-00f7-4f16-8aef-527f576cdad9/photo/$value',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'image/jpg'
      }
    })
  .then(function(response) {

    var base64 = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + hexToBase64(getBinary())
    vm.emails = base64;

    $log.debug(response.data);

  }, function(error) {
    $log.error('HTTP request to Mail API failed.');
  });
```

The only difference is that he photos I get back from the Graph API are unicode rather than ASCII.

Is there any existing example of how to embed a photo from the Microsoft Graph API onto a webpage? I've gone through every option provided by Stack Overflow posts without any success.

**Edit - Add Solution**

I ended up solving this a little differently than Yi Li did. Here is my solution:

Frontend:

```
<img src="{{email.image}}" />
```

Javascript:

```
    function getGroupImage(groupId)
    {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/' + groupId + '/photo/$value',
            responseType: 'blob',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/octet-binary'
            }
          })
        .then(function(response) {

          // Use FileReader to convert the image from a blob to a
          // base64-encoded string.
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = function() {
            deferred.resolve(reader.result);
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(response.data);

        }, function(error) {
          console.log('HTTP request to Group Photo API failed.');
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

I also found this link to be very useful: https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office/issues/154

It not only provides a work around to ADAL failures that I constantly ran into, but the solution that is provides also allows for editing plugins outside of Owa and Outlook.

A fully working example is here: https://github.com/seusher/OutlookAddin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I was able to solve this was by converting it to a base64 representation, adding the tag data needed for the image and setting the img src of that element to that.

Here is a code snippet of how I did this:

```
    var arr = new Uint8Array(results);

    //  Don't use fromCharCode.apply as it blows the stack with moderate size images
    var raw = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        raw = raw + String.fromCharCode(arr[i]);
    }
    var b64 = btoa(raw);
    var dataURL = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + b64;

    document.getElementById("img").src = dataURL;
    $scope.showImage = true;
```

Note that the 'img' element I used was defined on the HTML site; it was usually hidden, until I had the binary data to update it from this function.

You can see an example of this at: https://graphexplorerbeta.azurewebsites.net/src/api-explorer-helpers.js:81 at the handleImageResponse(...) function.

Let me know if you have any questions or clarifications.

Comment: I had forgotten to update this with my solution. I edited my original post with what I ended up doing, and marked your answer and the solution.